# Improve handling of errors for React | Redux | MERN App

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I think this question has a chance to be quite helpful / educational, and I will share a lot of what I have already done with this. To help elaborate on the question, here is an example of what a typical container component looks like for an app I am building (from a redux / data-flow perspective):

```
// Import React Components
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { fetchDataA } from '../actions/data-a-action.js';
import { fetchDataB } from '../actions/data-b-action.js';
import { fetchDataC } from '../actions/data-c-action.js';

class WhiteBoard extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.dispatch(fetchDataA());
        this.props.dispatch(fetchDataB());
        this.props.dispatch(fetchDataC());
    }

    render() {
        if(this.props.error1) { return <div> error message </div> }
        if(this.props.error2) { return <div> error message </div> }
        if(this.props.error3) { return <div> error message </div> }
        if(this.props.loading) { return <div> Loading Screen </div> }

        return (
            <div>
                <p> A website with only a p tag </p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(reduxState) {
    console.log('reduxState: ', reduxState);
    return {
        dataA: reduxState.DataAReducer.sportsData,
        dataB: reduxState.DataBReducer.sportsData,
        dataC: reduxState.DataCReducer.sportsData,

        loading: (reduxState.DataAReducer.loading ||
                  reduxState.DataBReducer.loading ||
                  reduxState.DataCReducer.loading),

        error1: reduxState.DataAReducer.error,
        error2: reduxState.DataBReducer.error,
        error3: reduxState.DataCReducer.error
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(WhiteBoard);
```

All of my Reducers are the same - the payloads have a `sportsData`, `loading`, and `error` that are returned. While the data is loading, `loading == true`. If the data fetching is successful, sportsData has the data I need, otherwise the error is returned.

For apps of mine that involve grabbing data from 5+ collections in my database, the mapStateToProps function becomes a mess of non-DRY code. Creating props error1, error2, error3, etc. also just feels like bad practice.

Is there a better-practice for this type of error/loading handling for data fetches with actions/reducers with redux? Or is how I'm doing it already the best practice?

**Edit:** let me know if sharing the actions/reducer code would be helpful. i did not want to over-bulk this post with too much info, but maybe those would help?

Answer (score 0):

You should call an error action that calls the same reducer regardless of the data call that's throwing the error.  something like:

```
try {
  const res = await fetchData()
  dispatch(success_data(data)
} catch (err) {
  dispatch(sameErrorAction)
}
```

Then you can do whatever with the data should there be an error but you don't have to have to handle each error separately.